# How to merge multiple audio/video stream

Tags: ffmpeg, recording

I have recordings of each side of a video call. Each side records only it's own audio/video. I want to merge/sync them so that they look like recording of a complete call.

I have time when each side start it's recording. e.g first from 0, second from 50 seconds after the first one started.

I found a lib ffmpeg and trying the same using it. So far, I am only able to map them into a single file in which they both start at same time. The problem is that when both input streams have different duration, lib triggers error related memory.

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]hstack[t]; [0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[b]" -map "[t]" -map "[b]" out.mp4
```

I see following error,

Error while filtering=28.0 size=     166kB time=00:00:06.58 bitrate= 207.1kbits/s speed=3.26x
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #1:1

Since both streams start at same time so their audio/video don't sync.

Cutting the long stream and then merging with shortest one then finally concatenating doesn't look like a good option for me.

Can you please suggest me how to achieve this without loosing audio/video?

Thanks,
R.

Comment: Upgrade to latest ffmpeg and check. There were some filter mem-related bugs that were fixed recently.

Comment: I have 3.3.3 win-64 static build  (http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/). It seems like it is the latest version?

Comment: By latest, I meant latest git build.